# Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\AndroidStudio\skins\pixel_2]!

Tags: android-studio

Помогите решить проблему. Путь переменной указывает верно на SDK, но все равно выдает ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После изменений переменных окружения рестартанули систему?

Comment: не используйте кирилицу в пути

Comment: Отдельно android studio перезапускал, потом полностью компьютер. Не помогло. Кириллицы вроде нет в пути

Comment: Ошибка ссылается на переменную ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, разве переменная TEMP будет влиять?